# Copy feature class from multiple gdb to a single gdb

Tags: arcpy, list, personal-geodatabase, workspace

I need to write a Python script that is copying. I want to copy a common feature class of these gdb to a single gdb

```
import os
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = ("D:/Planchas")

workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("", "Access")

print(workspaces)

for workspace in workspaces:
    featureSet = arcpy.ListDatasets("Toponimos")
    for fs in featureSet:
        featureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Orografia", "Point", fs)
        for fc in featureClasses:
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(
                    fc, 
                    os.path.join("C:/Users/Prueba",
                    os.path.splitext(fc)[0]))
```

When I try to run the code there is no error but the process is not carried out

Comment: Please remember to paste a script that doesn't need extensive editing by each person who would want to help you.  Clipping out the interpreter noise takes enough time to prevent assistance.

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?  Does it give an error?  If so, please include the full error message including line number.

Comment: When I try to run the code there is no error but the process is not carried out

Comment: What do you mean by a common feature class? A feature class which exists in all geodatabases?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your script.

1. You should change the workspace for each iteration of the feature
   datasets within the mdbs. Currently your script is looking for
   datasets called 'Toponimos" inside your `D:\Planchas` directory.
2. No need to add brackets around the workspace (`arcpy.env.workspace = ("D:/Planchas")`)
3. Also, your output path is not OK if you want to save to a gdb feature class.

```
import os, arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Planchas"

workspaces = arcpy.ListWorkspaces("", "Access")
print(workspaces)
for workspace in workspaces:
    arcpy.env.workspace = workspace
    featureSet = arcpy.ListDatasets("Toponimos")
    for fs in featureSet:
        featureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Orografia", "Point", fs)
        for fc in featureClasses:
            arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(fc,
                                          os.path.join("C:/Users/Prueba.gdb", fc))
```